# read nested variable from .env for laravel 5.1 (and docker)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

Laravel 5.1 is evaluating nested variables in .env oddly. The spec from [vlucas/phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#nesting-variables) is follows this: `CACHE_DIR="${BASE_DIR}/cache"`

However `DB_HOST="${MYSQLDB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}"` will return `"${MYSQLDB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}"` through http, which I can obviously not connect to.

Through phpunit `TESTING_DB_HOST="{$MYSQLDB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}"` will correctly return 172.17.0.2. Notice the placement of the `$` is incorrect. Placing the `$` in the correct position will return `"${MYSQLDB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}"`.

Changing the `$` placement for the http request does not matter, I do not receive an evaluated value.

I am using docker, I don't know if that has anything to do this problem. I am using this guide: [Laravel/docker](http://www.sitepoint.com/docker-and-dockerfiles-made-easy/)

Any thoughts on what is going on and how to get the mysql ip for http from a .env nested variable?